# Can unreal Engine runs with Microsoft Visual 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

Can unreal Engine4 runs with Microsoft Visual 2017?
Is that good?

Answer (score 1):

4.15 or later [supports](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/) 2017:

```
Unreal Engine Version | Visual Studio Version
---------------------------------------------
4.15 or Later           VS2017
4.10 to 4.14            VS2015
4.2 to 4.9              VS2013
```

As for if it's good, it's opinion-based, but I haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: So which version is better for creating FPS game

Comment: I don't see a reason to use an older version unless there is a specific need, so maybe try VS2017 and Unreal 4.17 first?

Comment: Can it support C#?

Comment: @MingLegend There is a third-party support for C# but I haven't tested it: https://mono-ue.github.io/